# Typeform-like form on Webflow, navigate and submit with enter key

Tags: javascript, webflow

I wish I could use the enter key to change the pages of a form (like Typeform). I would also like the enter key to allow form submission.

I used Keycodes this way. But by doing this, the form makes an infinite loop and it doesn't submit.

```
$ (document) .on ('keyup', function (event) {
if (event.which === 13) {
           $ ('. next'). trigger ('tap');
         }
       else if (event.which === 37) {
           $ ('. previous'). trigger ('tap');
         }
         });
```

Do you know how I can allow the user to navigate in the form with the enter key as well as submit it?

The link to my example: https://aureliebrebant.webflow.io/form

Thank you